# Can I get more info added to my Custom Output Settings in Photoshop (dimensions/color mode)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

When saving for the web, Photoshop lets you set some default Output Settings for the filename. Some of these options include the documents name, today's date, and the various slice names. I would like to get some other dynamic info added automatically when saving. Like the total dimensions(WxH) of the canvas,or the color mode (RGB/CMYK). Is there any way to get this info to show up?

Comment: Can you explain why you need this in the filename, rather than in the metadata, or retrieved by a script?

Answer (score 0):

You can use File > File Info in order to add metadata to an image. Then, when using Save For Web, change the "Metadata" drop down on the right and choose "All". By default the dimensions and color space (EXIF data) should be included in metadata when choosing All.

The canvas, on images which are saved via save for web, is always the same size as the image dimensions. There is never a Save For Web image which has a larger canvas than the image itself.

This will increase file sizes (kb), sometimes considerably.

I don't know what you mean by "get this info to show up."

Comment: By 'get this info to show up' I'm talking about the Output Settings where you can dictate how files are named when saved. Photoshop has a short list of variables you can use like doc. name, slide name, and date. But I would like to use things like dimensions and color mode too. Putting this info in the metadata won't get it into the filename. My goal is to save a file with a filename likethis: filename_480x60_rgb.ext

Comment: You would need scripting to alter the filename based on metadata. I'm sure such a script **could** be written. But I'm not the person to help with such a task.